# Creating bean using static method from another class

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

I have a factory class which has various static methods to return the instances of some classes. 
How can a bean be created in spring using static factory method in different class?

something like:

```
public class InstanceFactory
{    
  public static JellyBean getJellyBeanInstance()
  {
    return new JellyBean(); 
  }
}
```

I need a JellyBean.

Comment: Add example of your code

Comment: still no answer to this question?

Answer (score 4):

Just change your `getJellyBeanInstance()` method to non-static,
then you need:

```
<bean id="instanceFactory" class="InstanceFactory"/>

<bean id="yourBeanId" factory-bean="instanceFactory" factory-method="getJellyBeanInstance"/>
```

Comment: `class="YourFactoryClass"` shouldnt this be the name of the class whose instance needs to be created?

Comment: @varun you're right, that works if the static factory method is on the class itself, I'll update the answer.

Comment: what if static factory method is not on the class itself, its inside some other class

Comment: I really dont want my factory to be a bean itself.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:
[Spring Bean Instantiation with a static factory method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method)

For instance factory method, next section from the document should help.

Comment: I already know how it can be done if I create bean of my factory class, but i dont want to create any instance of my factory class. Lets say my factory class is abstract.